# Open folder in emacs and type name to match file

Tags: find-file

I have this line in my init.el:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") (lambda() (interactive) (find-file "~/Dropbox/myorgfiles")))
```

So when I type `C-c g` I get the directory contents of the `myorgfiles` folder.
But I would like to be able to start typing and get search results for that pattern within that `myorgfiles` folder.
How could I manage to do this? At the moment the individual keyboard strokes have different functions.

Comment: So `C-x C-f` and start typing - what am I missing?

Comment: I see that C-x C-f is binded to helm-find-files, and actually that is the function I could use. Instead, my function above calls find-file, and this function does not allow for start typing. I just fixed my above function like this: (global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") (lambda() (interactive) (helm-find-files "~/Dropbox/myorgfiles"))), and it WORKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @NickD said in a comment, what you want is just to call `find-file` interactively.  But you want it to do its thing in folder `~/Dropbox/myorgfiles`.

So you just need to bind `default-directory` to `~/Dropbox/myorgfiles/`.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (let ((default-directory  "~/Dropbox/myorgfiles/"))
                    (call-interactively #'find-file))))
```